# Cloud build error: failed to build: executing lifecycle. This may be the result of using an untrusted builder: failed with status code: 51

Tags: django, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-build, google-cloud-shell

I am trying to deploy a template Django project to cloud run using cloud shell from the following tutorial: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/cloud-run-django
In step 7, on running the command:

```
gcloud builds submit --pack image=gcr.io/${PROJECT_ID}/myimage
```

to build the application image, this error is coming:

> `ERROR: failed to build: exit status 1 ERROR: failed to build:
> executing lifecycle. This may be the result of using an untrusted
> builder: failed with status code: 51 ERROR ERROR: build step 0
> "gcr.io/k8s-skaffold/pack" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
>
> BUILD FAILURE: Build step failure: build step 0
> "gcr.io/k8s-skaffold/pack" failed: step exited with non-zero status: 1
> ERROR: (gcloud.builds.submit) build
> 75a52dae-9a4f-4591-af13-5fe1228533b4 completed with status "FAILURE"`

The file migration.yaml is same as the tutorial and I have followed all steps exactly as they were in the tutorial.
Can someone please help me with this error ?